# Riemann condition and integration

Tags: riemann-sum, riemann-integration

$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2,  & 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\[2ex]  
x+1, & 1 < x ≤ 2
\end{cases}
$$

Let $ε > 0$ be given

**Question**

Let $n ∈ \mathbb N$ be given. Explain why there is a Partition $P = \{\mathbf{X}_0,\mathbf{X}_1,\mathbf{X}_2,\ldots,\mathbf{X}_k\}$ of the interval $[0, 1- 1/n]$ for which $\sum_{i=1}^k (M_i-m_i)(X_i - X_{i-1}) < 1/3ε$

how do i even start with this ?
Sorry for reposting I made a error in the previous post so the question did not make sense

I think the following theorem may be of use:

> Let $f$ be defined and bounded on $[a,b]$. Then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ iff for every $ε >  0$ there exists a partition $P$ of $[a,b]$ such that $U(P) - L(P) < ε$

Comment: Essentially you have to explain that if you choose a number $k$ of points $x_0 , x_1 , ... , x_k$ in the interval $[0,1-1/n]$, $\sum_{i=0}^k (x_{i}^2 - x_{i-1}^2 )(x_i - x_{i-1}) < \epsilon$; do you see why? (See also the answer below).

Comment: "how do i even start with this ?" You could start by applying the very specific suggestions made on the other page... or the "game" can continue forever.

Comment: @Pythagoricus Not true for every partition of size $k$.

Comment: @Did I didn't mean that; $k$ is any number we might choose to do the work (lost in translation...)

Comment: @Pythagoricus Again: choosing $k$ large enough guarantees nothing.

Comment: @Did Forget about $k$! I just put it there, sorry if it's confusing. I didn't mean to say anything more that what the OP when they wrote 'there is a partition $P = {x_0 , x_1 , ... ,x_k}$'.

Comment: @Pythagoricus Thank you for the response you are very helpful :)

Comment: Likely it was intended that $M_i$ and $m_i$ are respectively the maximum and minimum of $f(x)$ on subinterval $[X_{i-1},X_i]$.  By omitting this setup of your problem, you've led yourself into a bog of confusion.

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the function $f$ coincides with $x \mapsto x^2$ on the interval $[0,1-1/n]$. If you know that a continuous function is Riemann integrable on a closed interval, you are done. Otherwise, you could also try to mimick the proof that an increasing function is integrable, as you can read in Chapter 6 of Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.

Comment: Thank you so much :) They gave us a Theorem that saying if f is monotone then it is riemann integrable